# angularjs : cannot call method from list comprehension in select

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

Im new to angularjs. Im trying to invoke a method from a list comprehension but unfortunately the script failes. take a look at the plunk http://plnkr.co/5uPj81.

when using a scope variable like the code below, everything works fine

```
Province:<select ng-model="portinForm.address.provinceCode" ng-options="province.code for province in ProvinceList"></select>
```

however, when using a method to get the array, i get an exception

```
Province:<select ng-model="portinForm.address.provinceCode" ng-options="province.code for province in getProvinceList()"></select>
```

Exception:

```
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":16,"oldVal":14}],[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":18,"oldVal":16}],[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":20,"oldVal":18}],[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":22,"oldVal":20}],[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":24,"oldVal":22}]]
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.4/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22ms…rInterceptedExpression%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A24%2C%22oldVal%22%3A22%7D%5D%5D
```

doesnt angular support this! or am I doing something worng.

thanks

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: The two lines you show seem identical. So the thing that you describe which is different, we'd need to see, not a repeat of the data.

Comment: i think this has something to with objects being updated inside getProvinceList(). Make sure you are not updating objects inside that function.

Comment: Can you post your code because you plunker have different code

Comment: Apologies for the mistakes in my question.

Comment: corrected plunk url and code snippets

Answer (score 3):

Angular will keep running digests until all view values settle down and stop changing.
This is described in the [documentation for $rootScope.Scope.$digest](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest).

However, your `getProvinceList()` function returns a new array of objects every time it's called. This means that Angular can never work out when the view is finished updating and will keep running digest cycles, eventually hits the 10 iteration limit and throws an exception to avoid an infinite digest loop.

It works with `ProvinceList` because the list is created once and isn't recreated after that.